# PermissionError: [Errno 13] when trying to run from NotePad++ but not from IDLE

Tags: python, notepad++

I have the following simple code:

```
fh = open('example.txt','w')
fh.write('something')
fh.close()
```

If I use Python's IDLE, the scripts works as intended, it creates a file called example.txt in the same directory that the script is in.

But, if I do the same from within Notepad++, using the "Run..." command and the command line `c:\python35\python.exe -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`, it opens the python window, opens the script file and gives a `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'example.txt'`

I don't know what this thing is doing, I suspect that its trying to write the example.txt file inside the python's directory and not where the script is. So, I changed the command line in the Run command in Notepad++ to simply `python -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"` (I have the python directory in the `%PATH%`), but it gives the same error.

I know this problem is more related to Notepad++ configuration than to a python problem, but any help will be appreciated.

I'm using Windows 10, python 3.5, Notepad++ 6.8.1

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try running NotePad++ as administrator

Comment: You could try to specify the full path of examlpe.txt: e.g. specify 'c:\Temp\example.txt'.

Comment: Running Notepad++ as administrator fixed it. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is what **Juxhin** said, Notepad++ must be run as administrator. I liked it was posted as an answer!!!

Comment: I suspect the issue is that it was setting the working directory to the wrong place. You sure example.txt isn't now getting written to, say, Notepad++'s install directory?